# Form Not Appearing in Weebly

Tags: cognito-forms, weebly

I recently created a Cognito Form and tried to embed it on a Weebly website. However, the code did not produce a form in the editor or when the website was published. I have used Weebly a long time and have never had any problem with inserting any code, be it forms or another widget.

I also tried embedding the form on a blog and this worked. I am wondering if anyone knows why Cognito forms is not compatible with Weebly or if there is something I can change that will fix this issue.

Not working page (in the white space): http://nayaktech1.weebly.com/quote.html

Working blog (all the way at the bottom above "follow by email"): http://blog.earthyes.org/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your site as well as the Javascript that Weebly loads, it looks as if there is a conflict between the code that Weebly loads and the code that Cognito Forms loads.

Specifically, Weebly defines Array.prototype.remove as a function that takes in an element index and removes the item at that index.  Cognito defines Array.remove as:

```
function (n,t){var i=p(n,t);return i>=0&&n.splice(i,1),i>=0}
```

while Weebly defines it as:

```
function(e,t){var i=this.slice((t||e)+1||this.length);return this.length=0>e?this.length+e:e,this.push.apply(this,i)}`
```

Because of this, Cognito is getting an unexpected result when calling Array.remove.  At this point, the best option would be to segregate Cognito's code from Weebly's by embedding the form in an iframe with code similar to this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.cognitoforms.com/NyTechInc/RequestAQuote"></iframe>
```

If you would like additional help embedding the form, please feel free to contact us via our "Request Help" link from the [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) site.

Disclaimer: I'm an engineer on the Cognito Forms team